# Spring MVC MQTT inbound messages not coming

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, mqtt, mosquitto

I configured MQTT in spring mvc application, howewever when I am trying to print something on console from command prompt, it is not printing. Code snnipet is <

```
@Bean
    public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();

        options.setServerURIs(new String[] { "tcp://localhost:1883" });
        options.setUserName("admin");
        String pass = "123456";
        options.setPassword(pass.toCharArray());
        options.setCleanSession(true);

        factory.setConnectionOptions(options);

        return factory;
    }
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MessageProducer inbound() {
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("serverIn",
                mqttClientFactory(), "#");

        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setQos(2);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
        //adapter.setOutputChannelName("mqttInputChannel");
        return adapter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {               
                String topic = message.getHeaders().get(MqttHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC).toString();
                if(topic.equals("myTopic")) {
                    System.out.println("This is the topic");
                }
                System.out.println(message.getPayload());
            }

        };
    }
>
```

I have installed Mosquitto on my windows and from there I need to check if this handler method is working buy trying to print. But I could not.[image: Trying to give this message from cmd]

Comment: I'm not a spring person, but I assume you are missing an annotation to actually subscribe to the topic `mytopic` (or a wildcard that would include it)

Comment: I checked, it is not the issue. My application is listening to port 1883 in localhost for any messages from broker. Strange part is that the same application is running on spring boot.

Comment: If the spring application is running on a different computer or device from the broker, `localhost` is not going to work; you'll need the actual name or IP address of the computer the broker is running on.

Comment: I am running spring application and mqtt message broker on same computer, therefore using 'localhost'.

Answer (score 0):

I made the below separate configuration file and it worked.

```
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan(basePackages = "com.dr")
@Configuration
public class MqttBeansConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {//config
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
//propeties
        options.setServerURIs(new String[] { "localhost:1883" });
        //options.setUserName("admin");
        //String pass = "123456";
        //options.setPassword(pass.toCharArray());
        //options.setCleanSession(true);

        factory.setConnectionOptions(options);

        return factory;
    }
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {//config
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MessageProducer inbound() { //config
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("serverIn",
                mqttClientFactory(), "#");

        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setQos(2);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
        return adapter;
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                String topic = message.getHeaders().get(MqttHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC).toString();
                if(topic.equals("myTopic")) {
                    System.out.println("This is the topic");
                }
                System.out.println(message.getPayload());
            }

        };
    }
    
    
    /*@Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttOutboundChannel() {//leave it
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttOutboundChannel") //leave it
    public MessageHandler mqttOutbound() {
        //clientId is generated using a random number
        MqttPahoMessageHandler messageHandler = new MqttPahoMessageHandler("serverOut", mqttClientFactory());
        messageHandler.setAsync(true);
        messageHandler.setDefaultTopic("#");
        messageHandler.setDefaultRetained(false);
        return messageHandler;
    }

*/
}
```